# meteor deploy then after having receiving url whith the command mongo --url http://<sitename>.meteor.com/ try to connect to the url whith robomongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've run meteor deploy sitename : it's ok

Then I want to connect to the database whith robomongo, so i run the command : 

`mongo --url http://sitename.meteor.com/`

I receive an url of this type :

`mongodb://client-d7a066d2:8c9b29f5-180e-d57a-3ba7-1b2037c2aeb1@production-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/libreboardandy_meteor_com`

This adress is valid during one minute.

In Robomongo I start a new connection, give a name and paste the url.

Then I click on the connect button.

But I have an error message...

`Cannot connect to MongoD ....`

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so try use **mongo -U** command ;

```
meteor mongo -U sitename.meteor.com
// mongodb://username:password@production-db-d1.meteor.io:27017/database_name
```

**:** 
client-d7a066d2:8c9b29f5-180e-d57a-3ba7-1b2037c2aeb1

[image]

set username and password

[image]

ok click test.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your project folder in your local environment (e.g. Terminal in OSX)
2. Type `meteor mongo --url YOURDEPLOYEDAPP.meteor.com`

> You will get something like this:
>
> `mongodb://client-49e5fcc0:d3d4c092-adc9-4966-57a9-a321caaa6415@production-db-d2.meteor.io:27017/yourdeployedapp_meteor_com`

That mongodb URL contains, in this order:

```
mongodb://username:password@server-address:port/database_name
```

3. So now in Robomongo (or your local DB client), create a new connection using this information, like this screenshot:
   [image: Connection settings for Robomongo DB client connecting to a MongoDB Server hosted by Meteor]

[image: Robomongo client on OX connected to remote MongoDB on Meteor]